# Implementing REST API digital signature

Tags: python, php, digital-signature

I'm currently trying to implement a minimal REST API with digital signature.

I understand that the underlying concept is that the sender sign the payload with its private key using HMAC and that the receiver verify this signature with the public key.

However I have some difficulties implementing a working example.

My API is implemented in PHP and the client in python.

I verify requests in PHP as follow

```
public function verify_request(Request $request)
{
    $method = $request->method();
    $timestamp = $request->header("timestamp");
    $public_key = $request->header("api-key");
    $signature = $request->header("signature");
    $url = $request->fullUrl();

    $data = $method.$timestamp.$url;

    $result = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    Logger::info("Result : ".$result);
    return $result;
}
```

I already successfully signed requests on several other APIs using this minimal example in python

```
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac
import time

public_key = ""
private_key = ""

method = "GET"
base_url = "https://testing-api.com"
endpoint = "/private/test"
url = base_url + endpoint
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

signature_data = method + timestamp + url

signature = hmac.new(private_key.encode("utf-8"), signature_data.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

headers = {
    "api-key": public_key,
    "timestamp": timestamp,
    "signature": signature,
}

response = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

However what I don't understand is what kind of keys are used.

For example I generated RSA keys as follow

```
public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAL7Jz6mHX1cau3wlc6QrGW+kcVHO0HPj
iwUDxdM1B8KSLgkfle4+Snq6HhOp5VXdQXZkYF4u9ctWbx/sB2oiD1sCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

private_key = """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAvsnPqYdfVxq7fCVz
pCsZb6RxUc7Qc+OLBQPF0zUHwpIuCR+V7j5KeroeE6nlVd1BdmRgXi71y1ZvH+wH
aiIPWwIDAQABAkAnxyvkzLS0FH7Cg4x4zgOfo0l9JQGRJ//0K7UzM/tKNZOy881O
+qEDld7XMaUOmyGd/FxSskrJrzWTSqEZtQ8BAiEA7wsKUjGWFyTfuMkj/3/E0XI2
YYEaTRpROl4NN6FUttcCIQDMUnn7JDovxYlp17QhyOb41qc1I402QZ6zNiz33ytP
HQIgA2rr/drZo4ESdcjia9++x6PTZTd8Ucfji2sW00nKNUcCIFo7Oh9Mml2qcMrL
NYOOA2J0+RaggqYpSHqAPE+iwK+JAiB2YbMutRh5EDyTcI2ql/hYFLlAJVT/E1AN
/ItM1KCQQQ==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
```

But it doesn't match the format of the API keys I tested on several other APIs, and when I try to pass the public key into the header I got the following error

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Invalid return character or leading space in header: api-key
```

For example on an API I tested, the keys had the following format

```
public_key = "Tub3FH4CLjHezvRcSKdeE18a9VrtzL"
private_key = "tBssW3InKRq09OMLkveyuZ65LDRokjVX8FXO0CL5VpdaV73NWayUvJSSAtCs"
```

But when I try to use those API keys for signing into my python script I have the following error on the PHP

```
ErrorException: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key
```

So I have two issues here about the API key format.

First I would like to know what kind of keys are used by those APIs so I can have keys as simple strings instead of multi-line strings.

Secondly I'd like to understand why those API keys are not considered correct by `openssl_verify`, since I suppose that how the signature are verified.

**Edit:** As @Toppaco said in his answer, my issue came from the fact that I thought those APIs were using asymmetric keys and only keeping the public key when in fact they use two unrelated keys, one for authentication, and one for signing, thus my confusion.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to try and use an existing standard and some library that implements it instead of rolling your own: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-message-signatures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse two signing concepts, [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). An HMAC uses the same secret key on both sides, RSA applies different keys on both sides, which form a keypair (private and public key). The private key is secret and is used for signing. The public is not secret and is passed to the verifying side where it is used for verification. For more information s. e.g. [How to decide whether to use digital signature (RSA) or HMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/72537). Both mechanisms ensure data integrity, RSA additionally verifies the signer, s. e.g. [JWT: Choosing between HMAC and RSA](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/220185).

The key types of both are completely different. An HMAC uses a (random) byte sequence as key, RSA requires certain parameters (modulus, private exponent, public exponent etc.) which are provided in different key formats.
For example, your posted public key is a PEM encoded RSA public key in X.509/SPKI format and your posted private key a PEM encoded RSA private key in PKCS#8 format.
Note that both keys are too small with a (modulus) size of 512 bits. Nowadays, for security reasons, they must be at least 2048 bits in size.

Your PHP code uses RSA (verifying with the public key), your Python code applies an HMAC. Both are incompatible, you must also use RSA in the Python code (signing with the private key).

Without further information I can't contextualize the keys *Tub...* and *tBs...*. But they cannot be used as HMAC keys because HMAC applies the same key on both sides. And they are obviously not RSA keys either.

---

Edit: According to the [documentation](https://docs.delta.exchange/#generating-an-api-key) linked by the OP in the comments, the two posted keys `public_key = "Tub..."` and `private_key = "tBs..."` are an API key and API secret for [authenticating requests](https://docs.delta.exchange/?python#authentication) to the Delta Exchange API. The API secret is used for signing *and* verifying the requests with an HMAC, as shown in the [sample code](https://docs.delta.exchange/?python#signing-a-message) of the documentation. In particular, API secret and API key do not form a related key pair consisting of a private and public key as used e.g. in the context of RSA.

Comment: I understand what you say, however on the APIs I tried (and it's the same for several of them), the signature is generated by the sender with the private key and is verified with the public key by the receiver.
I asked this question : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/106925/digital-signature-with-private-key-on-exchange/106926#106926
Which seems to confirm that a signature generated on a payload with a private key can be verified with a public key.
I just don't understand what kind of key is used and how.

Comment: @Arkaik - Unfortunately, *...however on the APIs I tried...* is too little information to identify the algorithm used. Can you provide more information, a link or preferably a code?

Comment: Sure, for example on this API : https://docs.delta.exchange/#signing-a-message

The python example works for this API and the keys I shown where generated from here.

I just don't understand what are the keys used and how they can verify the signature without having the private key since they are using HMAC.

Many crypto exchanges use the same authentication method and I don't really understand it.

Comment: Otherwise a full connector can be found here https://github.com/delta-exchange/python-rest-client

Comment: @Arkaik - I took a look at the documentation. Based on the descriptions and the code example in the chapters *Generating an API Key* and *Signing a Message* I assume that with `public_key` you mean the *API key* and with `private_key` the *API secret*. Is that right? If so, from what do you conclude that both form a key pair in the sense of private and public key?

Comment: @Arkaik - According to [this snippet](https://docs.delta.exchange/?python#signing-a-message) the API secret is used as HMAC key (as in your code). But why shouldn't the API secret also be used for verification? Possibly you mean because the API key is also sent, that this is used for verification. But there may be also other reasons for sending the API key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254214/discussion-between-topaco-and-arkaik).